# Rails association with multiple instances of same relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 2 models, `Employee` and `Approval`.  I want to set up an association such that an `:approval` `belongs_to` 2 different employees (1 manager, 1 subordinate).  How might I set that up?  I would want to be able to pull all approvals for a manager as well as for the subordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it declaring explicitly `class_name` on `belongs_to` and `has_many` and `foreign_key` on `has_many`

```
class Approval < ApplicationModel
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'Employee'
  belongs_to :subordinate, class_name: 'Employee'
end

class Employee < ApplicationModel
  has_many :manager_approvals, foreign_key: :manager_id, class_name: 'Approval'
  has_many :subordinate_approvals, foreign_key: :subordinate_id, class_name: 'Approval'
end
```

Docs:

- [has many](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)
- [belongs to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)

Comment: when I call `Employee.first.manager_approvals` I get the error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Employee::ManagerApproval`

Comment: ^^ that does it!

Comment: Forgot to add `class_name` on `Employee` side. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

1 => Add a migration add `manager_id` column to `Employee`

```
rails g migration add_manager_id_to_employee manager_id:integer
```

2 => Self-Referential Association to Employee model

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager, optional: true
  has_many : subordinates, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
end
```

3 =>

```
class Approval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  has_one :manager, { where("employees.manager_id= nil ") }
  has_one :subordinate, { where("employees.manager_id= self.employee_id") }
end
```